How to fix volume distribution (geo nodes)>
I'm distributing an icosphere to a volume of a text object. As in the screenshot, it does not evenly distribute. Is there a way to fix this uneven distribution? As you can see, top and bottom portions are almost empty while the center is really dense. 

You do not distribute points in volume, but on faces - that's why the node is called Distribute Points on Faces. It only results in having points inside the number because you are using the Mesh Boolean with the grid faces to get some faces inside the number.
However, the stack of grids is smaller than the number, resulting in only partially having points inside it, the parts outside the intersecting grids only have points on the surface of the number - because they are distributed on faces, not inside a volume.

It becomes even more obvious when you change the solver type in the Mesh Boolean node from Float to Exact then the difference works only where you actually have grid inside the number and the parts where the grid does not overlap the number is removed:

So you either have to make both objects matching each other by either scaling down the number or increasing the size of the grid stack, or you skip all this mesh boolean stuff and use a Distribute Points in Volume node after converting the number's mesh with a Mesh to Volume node:

And if you want to get the shape of the original mesh more clearly, you can add points to the surface as well like before (just without the grids an Mesh Boolean part) and join them with the ones in the volume:

The only thing that's missing here is, the Distribute Points in Volume_ node has no Poisson Disk option where you can set a Distance Min value. If this is important for your result then you probably should do it like before just with better matching sizes.
